# Ways to deal with React page flickering on re-renders (functional components)

Tags: reactjs

A lot of things are causing my React functional components to flicker as new data comes in from various fetches and everything is constantly redrawn top-to-bottom.

For example, if I have a top-level `App` component which somewhere down the line includes a `MyForm` component, and the `App` does an initial fetch of DB Lookups which I depend on in the `MyForm` (passed as a prop, `lookups={lookups}`), the `MyForm` will flicker as it redraws itself on receiving the new prop values.

**App**

```
useEffect(() => {    
    fetchLookups();
}, []);     

const fetchLookups = async () => {
    const url = '/api/general/lookups';
    try {
        const responseLookups = await axios.get(url);
        setLookups(responseLookups.data);
    }
}
```

**MyForm** - will flicker - note also I have to check for the Non-NULL Fetch result from `App`, which is a pain

```
<Form.Control 
value={props.lookups &&
       props.lookups.filter(item => item.id === 30)
                            .map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    item.description
                                );
                            })
/>
```

Also, in the `MyForm` component, there are lots of use inits/listeners with `useEffect(.., [])` and they will also cause the form to re-render. I have no way of knowing what the order will be on all those inits/listeners.

So my questions are, what's the best way to deal with this flickering?

1. Can I detect when a functional component is **fully rendered**, to show a loading spinner covering the full initialization sequence?
2. Can I block re-renders in any way?

Comment: 1. The useEffect hook which triggers the function `fetchLookups` will run only when the component is rendered . `useEffect` doesn't fire before it. 
 2. Yeah there are multiple ways to optimize the rendering performance in react. But it will be easier to help if you add some code.

Comment: This might give you a better picture on the hooks flow - https://www.bram.us/2019/03/11/react-hook-flow-diagram/ . If you notice here running the effect is the last thing which react does .

Comment: I understand that but I don't want the presented result to be visible (either blocked or darkened) until the screen is fully ready.